# log4net log file get log with a lot of other information which we dint write

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using log4net feature in my windows based .net application, which interact with different 3rd party com dll.  so i could see the log file get log with a lot of other information which we dint write for logging.
so i just want know if any configuration i missed so that it could log only those information which we intent to log.

details

```
application : c# windows based 3.5 .net framework log4net version:  1.2
```

sample

```
2013-11-26 05:16:11,481 [15] INFO - TKS.DataDriver.DataDriver - LoadWorkBook : start LoadWorkBook operation
2013-11-26 05:16:13,653 [15] INFO - TKS.DataDriver.MsExcel.Common - inside method IsFileLocked 
2013-11-26 05:16:19,028 [15] INFO - TKS.DataDriver.DataDriver - MergeTestCaseEntities : Merging all Test Case Entities.
2013-11-26 05:16:19,028 [15] INFO - TKS.DataDriver.DataDriver - LoadWorkBook : monitoringFlag: False  MonitorQTPstatusOnOff:  ON
2013-11-26 05:16:19,028 [15] INFO - TKS.DataDriver.DataDriver - LoadWorkBook : Asyncronus call for status check of the QTP.
2013-11-26 05:16:19,028 [15] INFO - TKS.DataDriver.DataDriver - DataLoadTestSet : DataLoad method call completed and result is : True
2013-11-26 05:16:19,028 [15] INFO - LogCatReplay - CProxy_IQTFuncLibMgrEvents::FireHelper Start. DispID = 4 Func=CProxy_IQTFuncLibMgrEvents<class CQTFuncLibMgr>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionengine\qtfunclibmgrcp.h Line=16 ThreadID=4636
2013-11-26 05:16:19,028 [15] INFO - LogCatReplay - UnitExecutionEngine: CProxy_IQTASUnitExecutionEngineEvents::FireHelper Start. DispID = 7 Func=CProxy_IQTASUnitExecutionEngineEvents<class CQTASUnitExecutionEngine>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionengine\qtasunitexecutionenginecp.h Line=15 ThreadID=4636
2013-11-26 05:16:19,028 [15] INFO - LogCatReplay - UnitExecutionEngine: CProxy_IQTASUnitExecutionEngineEvents::FireHelper End Func=CProxy_IQTASUnitExecutionEngineEvents<class CQTASUnitExecutionEngine>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionengine\qtasunitexecutionenginecp.h Line=39 ThreadID=4636
2013-11-26 05:16:19,043 [16] INFO - TKS.DataDriver.DataDriver - MonitorQTPstatus kick ON Now.
2013-11-26 05:16:19,059 [1] INFO - HP.QTP.QEEE.ExecutionMediator.Execution.ExecutionStatusResolver - Instance 0: Runtime status is updated to Done(micGeneral)
2013-11-26 05:16:19,059 [15] INFO - LogCatReplay - CProxy_IQTFuncLibMgrEvents::FireHelper Start. DispID = 5 Func=CProxy_IQTFuncLibMgrEvents<class CQTFuncLibMgr>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionengine\qtfunclibmgrcp.h Line=16 ThreadID=4636
2013-11-26 05:16:19,059 [15] INFO - LogCatReplay - UnitExecutionEngine: CProxy_IQTASUnitExecutionEngineEvents::FireHelper Start. DispID = 8 Func=CProxy_IQTASUnitExecutionEngineEvents<class CQTASUnitExecutionEngine>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionengine\qtasunitexecutionenginecp.h Line=15 ThreadID=4636
2013-11-26 05:16:19,059 [15] INFO - LogCatReplay - cCProxy_IQTTestExecutionEngineEvents::FireHelper Start. DispID = 16 Func=CProxy_IQTTestExecutionEngineEvents<class CQTTestExecutionEngine>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionengine\qttestexecutionenginecp.h Line=15 ThreadID=4636
2013-11-26 05:16:19,059 [1] INFO - LogCatReplay - ExecutionSite: CProxy_IQTTestExecutionEngineEvents::FireHelper Start. DispID = 16 Func=CProxy_IQTTestExecutionEngineEvents<class CQTTestExecutionSite>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionsite\qttestexecutionsitecp.h Line=17 ThreadID=880
2013-11-26 05:16:19,059 [1] INFO - LogCatReplay - ExecutionSite: CProxy_IQTTestExecutionEngineEvents::FireHelper End Func=CProxy_IQTTestExecutionEngineEvents<class CQTTestExecutionSite>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionsite\qttestexecutionsitecp.h Line=41 ThreadID=880
2013-11-26 05:16:19,059 [15] INFO - LogCatReplay - ExecutionEngine: CProxy_IQTTestExecutionEngineEvents::FireHelper End Func=CProxy_IQTTestExecutionEngineEvents<class CQTTestExecutionEngine>::FireHelper File=e:\ft\qtp\win32_release\11.52.467.0_clean\qtp\backend\executionengine\app\qtexecutionengine\qttestexecutionenginecp.h Line=52 ThreadID=4636
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard method of declaring the logger, eg

```
    internal static readonly log4net.ILog log =  log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

then in your log4net configuration file, you can disable logging except for your own code based on the namespaces of your classes.

For example, if you only wanted to log the lines from TKS.DataDriver, then your config file could contain something like

```
<root>
  <level value="OFF" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
<logger name="TKS.DataDriver">
  <level value="INFO" />
</logger>
```

You can add other namespaces if you need them or just use "TKS" etc.

Comment: here we have one problem, as my other logger assembly name  is- TKS.DataDriver.MsExcel.Common so i would like to allow the logger which is start with name "TKS"